# Sending Copy of signed Documents to a non-signer

Tags: docusignapi

I am using C# for DocuSign.

I want to send the signed documents to a list of recipients after the documents are signed. Is there a possible way to do this?

Thanks
Amulya Dutta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add those recipients (last in routing order) as CC recipients in the workflow, once all signers have completed the signing then DocuSign will send the completed envelope email to the CC recipients. Other way of doing is using API by forwarding the completed envelope ("765295a6-4b0c-4df9-b4a3-00e5c311bc8e") to a any one, in doing this way it will consume one more envelope for you.

```
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/<accountId>/envelopes?completed_documents_only=true

{
    "status":"sent",
    "emailSubject": "Forwarded Envelope",
    "envelopeId":"765295a6-4b0c-4df9-b4a3-00e5c311bc8e",
    "recipients": {
        "carbonCopies": [{
        "name": "1",
        "email": "signerEmail@gmail.com",
        "routingOrder": 1,
        "recipientId": "1"
    }]
    }
}
```